# how to change syntax Typescript to javascript React native

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

i'm building Raect Native with Expo, trying to make custom dropdown and i find and article wit an awesome expiation how to do that [here](https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-custom-react-native-dropdown/)

the code written with typeScript  syntax, but my project using a javaScript syntax so

1. how can i change the code syntax's to work on my project?
2. can use both Typescript and javascript on one project (so build the reusable component with  Typescript)?

> ```
> interface Props {
>   label: string;
> }
>
> const Dropdown: FC<Props> = ({ label }) => {
>   const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);
>
>   const toggleDropdown = () => {
>     setVisible(!visible);
>   };
>
>   const renderDropdown = () => {
>     if (visible) {
>       return (
>           <Text style={styles.dropdown}>
>             This is where the dropdown will be rendered.
>           </Text>
>       );
>     }
>   };
>
>   return (
>     <TouchableOpacity
>       style={styles.button}
>       onPress={toggleDropdown}
>     >
>       {renderDropdown()}
>       <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{label}</Text>
>       <Icon type='font-awesome' name='chevron-down'/>
>     </TouchableOpacity>
>   );
> }
> ```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A js script is a valid ts script so you can 'use both'.

(In fact every thing is typescript (sometimes without types))

To make this full javascript you have to suppress types and interfaces, like this :

```
// interface Props {
//   label: string;
// }

// const Dropdown: FC<Props> = ({ label }) => {
const Dropdown = ({ label }) => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false);

  const toggleDropdown = () => {
    setVisible(!visible);
  };

  const renderDropdown = () => {
    if (visible) {
      return (
          <Text style={styles.dropdown}>
            This is where the dropdown will be rendered.
          </Text>
      );
    }
  };

  return (
    <TouchableOpacity
      style={styles.button}
      onPress={toggleDropdown}
    >
      {renderDropdown()}
      <Text style={styles.buttonText}>{label}</Text>
      <Icon type='font-awesome' name='chevron-down'/>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  );
}
```